# Python: Remove [] character, and add new lines

Tags: json, python-3.x, csv, elasticsearch

I am able to successfully convert csv to json. I am also trying to upload the data into ElasticSearch so the format is little different, that why I need to convert this into a different kind of json format.

1. So, I am trying to remove starting and ending '[' and ']' from the json file.
2. Also, I am trying to insert '{"index" : {}}' for every new line of the data row.
3. create new line like pretty print

Data:

```
id,team_name,team_members
123,"Biology, Neurobiology ","Ali Smith, Jon Doe"
234,Mathematics,Jane Smith 
345,"Statistics, Probability","Matt P, Albert Shaw"
456,Chemistry,"Andrew M, Matt Shaw, Ali Smith"
678,Physics,"Joe Doe, Jane Smith, Ali Smith "
```

Code:

```
import csv
import sys
import json

#EDIT THIS LIST WITH YOUR REQUIRED JSON KEY NAMES
fieldnames=["id","team_name","team_members"]

def convert(filename):
 csv_filename = filename[0]
 print "Opening CSV file: ",csv_filename
 f=open(csv_filename, 'r')
 next(f) #skip the headers
 csv_reader = csv.DictReader(f,fieldnames)
 json_filename = csv_filename.split(".")[0]+".json"
 print "Saving JSON to file: ",json_filename
 jsonf = open(json_filename,'w')
 data = json.dumps([r for r in csv_reader])
 jsonf.write(data)
 f.close()
 jsonf.close()

if __name__=="__main__":
 convert(sys.argv[1:])

 # How to run?: python csvtojsonfile.py myCSVfile.csv
```

Current output:

```
[{"team_name": "Biology, Neurobiology ", "team_members": "Ali Smith, Jon Doe", "id": "123"}, {"team_name": "Mathematics", "team_members": "Jane Smith ", "id": "234"}, {"team_name": "Statistics, Probability", "team_members": "Matt P, Albert Shaw", "id": "345"}, {"team_name": "Chemistry", "team_members": "Andrew M, Matt Shaw, Ali Smith", "id": "456"}, {"team_name": "Physics", "team_members": "Joe Doe, Jane Smith, Ali Smith ", "id": "678"}]
```

Final Output Needed:

```
{"index" : {}}
{"team_name": "Biology, Neurobiology ", "team_members": "Ali Smith, Jon Doe", "id": "123"}
{"index" : {}}
{"team_name": "Mathematics", "team_members": "Jane Smith ", "id": "234"}
{"index" : {}}
{"team_name": "Statistics, Probability", "team_members": "Matt P, Albert Shaw", "id": "345"}
{"index" : {}}
{"team_name": "Chemistry", "team_members": "Andrew M, Matt Shaw, Ali Smith", "id": "456"}
{"index" : {}}
{"team_name": "Physics", "team_members": "Joe Doe, Jane Smith, Ali Smith ", "id": "678"}
```

Notice: I have removed comma, created '{"index" : {}}', and created new line. I appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to print it like that you can loop over the list like this

```
for i in data:
    print("index {}")
    print(i)
```

if you want it to look like that in a file you can use dumps arguments to change the look, you can't remove the "[]".

```
json.dump(jsonf, [r for r in csv_reader], indent=2)# this will output to a file, you don't need a .write()
```